# jQuery - scrolling loading. 

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a sort of infinite scroll on my own. The reason i'm not using Infinite is because I'm not gonna use it in Wordpress.

It's working, except for that I need to use the on.() method, I just can't figure out how to do it.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        $('.wait-please').show();
        latestTask();
    }
});

function latestTask()
{
    $id = $(".latestTask:last").attr("taskid");
    $.post("/includes/classes/handler.php?do=lastTask", { lastId : $id },
    function(data){
        if(data){
            //alert(data);
            $('.latestTask:last').after(data);
        }
        $('.wait-please').hide();
    });
}
```

The function latestTask calls a php script, where I'm echoing all the new posts. The problem is that it keeps calling the same ten because I need to on.() method to bind the new elements.

But where and how would I use On in this situation? For what I see I need to specify an event like click. But I dont have a click event?

The structure of the retrieved data is following:

```
echo "<div style='font-size:20px;color:#f90;' class='latestTask' taskid='$row[lookupId]'>$row[lookupId]</div>";
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the line of id's im getting when scrolling:

75
74
73
75
74
73
72
71
70
72
71
70
69
68
67
66
65
64
66
65
64
63
62
61
63
62
61
60
57
55
60
57
55
43
40
38
43
40
38
33
29
22
33
29
22

As you can see there's some very weird results from the database calls: 72, 71, 70, 72, 70. And it looks like I have to make it unable for the user to "double-scroll".. But how?

Comment: I can't see why your problem should be related to the `on()` method: every time you scroll the page you reference to a new jQuery selection, also including the new elements you loaded via ajax... data elements retrieved have the class `.latestTask` applied?

Comment: Maybe it's not my problem. Actually I just realised that 1st time it loads I'm getting the 10 next (true), 2nd time i'm getting the same 10 (false).. It is like it's duplicating the database call. So it's using the same id 2 times. How do I prevent this? :-S

Comment: could you post the markup contained in `data` variable?

Comment: What is the structure of the data returned from the ajax call?

Comment: I've updated the question with the retrieved data from the database.

Comment: the new element inserted has the taskid attribute you're expecting ?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the expected ID. I've found out that the problem comes that it's loading 2 times and the using the same ID. But then sometimes it's picking some old posts...

Comment: You only need to use `.on()` to respond to event(s), eg. to start/stop the auto scrolling in response to user clicks.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yeah, I got that I don't need to use .on() :)

Comment: I've updated the question, with the real issue, and a beg for help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do not fire the ajax request twice.

It is difficult to understand why this might be happening without seeing the full page in action..

Try this

```
var fetchingTasks = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        $('.wait-please').show();
        if (!fetchingTasks) {
          fetchingTasks = true;
          latestTask();
        }
    }
});

function latestTask()
{
    $id = $(".latestTask:last").attr("taskid");
    $.post("/includes/classes/handler.php?do=lastTask", { lastId : $id },
    function(data){
        if(data){
            //alert(data);
            $('.latestTask:last').after(data);
        }
        $('.wait-please').hide();
        fetchingTasks = false;
    });
}
```